# Point SSH / SFTP to specific folder

Tags: ssh, nautilus, filemanager, nemo, caja

Is there a way to instruct an SSH server to point to a specific folder when a client connects using a file manager such as Nautilus, Caja, or Nemo, instead of pointing to root '/'? For instance point to the folder `/mnt/sdb1/files`. Would the below folder become inaccessible to the connecting client?

Comment: In other words, changing the $HOME directory for a user?

Comment: @PSA Yes, kind of that.